# Keeping a running list on a page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, list

I'm working on creating a web page that will allow a user to play a simple "Guess my Number" game. The game itself is working properly, however I am supposed to keep a running list of the numbers the user has guessed on the web page and also to let them know if they guess a number that they have already guessed. This is my first time working with Javascript and I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this.

I'm sure I would need to create a variable such as "num" that would hold the numbers they've already guessed, but not sure how to do this since I don't want to replace the number already stored in this variable.

Here is the code I have so far, like I said, this portion of the code works properly, just not sure how to go about what I've described.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
        <title>Guess My Number</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var game = {
                num : 0,
                turns : 1,
                reset : function() {
                    this.turns = 1;
                    this.newNum();
                },
                newNum : function() {
                    this.num = parseInt(Math.random() * 10) +1;
                },
                guessNumber : function(guess) {
                    try {
                        guess = parseInt(guess);
                    }
                    catch(e) {
                        alert("Enter a guess!");
                        this.turns++;
                        return false;
                    }

                    if (guess == this.num) {
                        alert("Correct! It took you " + this.turns + " turns to guess my number.");
                        document.getElementById("guess").value = " ";
                        return true;
                    }
                    else if(guess > this.num) {
                        alert("Your guess is too high. Try again.");
                        this.turns++;
                        document.getElementById("guess").value = " ";
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Your guess is too low. Try again.");
                        this.turns++;
                        document.getElementById("guess").value = " ";
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            };

            function guessNumber() {
                var guess = document.getElementById("guess").value;
                game.guessNumber(guess);
                textbox = null;
            }

            function resetGame() {
                game.reset();
                document.getElementById("guess").value = " ";
            }

            resetGame();
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Would You Like To Play A Game?</h1>
        <h2>Thank you for checking out my game. Good luck!</h2>
        <h3>Created by Beth Tanner</h3>
        <h2>Directions:</h2>
        <p>
            The game is very simple. I am thinking of a number between 1
            and 10. It is your job to guess that number. If you do not guess
            correctly on your first attempt, don't worry, you can keep guessing 
            until you guess the correct number.
        </p>
        <p>
        Your Guess: <input type="text" id="guess" size="10" />
        <br />
        <input type="button" value="Sumbit Guess" onclick="guessNumber()" />
        <input type="reset" value="Reset Game" onclick="resetGame()"/>
        </p>
        <h3>Here Are Your Guesses So Far:</h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize an empty array like so

```
var tries = [];
```

Every time the user guesses a number, use the `.push` method of the array to append the number to it.

```
tries.push(guess);
```

To check if the user has tried a number already, check if the array method `.indexOf` returns a value different than `-1`

```
if (tries.indexOf(guess) != -1) //User has tried that number already
```

To show the values on the page, you can use the array `.join` method.

```
document.querySelector("#tries").textContent = tries.join(', ');
```

Comment: Would this array go in my game object, or somewhere else in the code?

Comment: It's up to you mate. It can go in the object or outside. You seem to have put all your game stuff inside that object, so you could put the array there as well.

Comment: I'm getting a little thrown off by the document.querySelector... portion, not sure where this would need to go?

Comment: This is just the equivalent of doing `document.getElementById("tries")`

Comment: Ok, I see. So would it need to be placed after each guess?

Answer (score 0):

To keep a collections of guessed numbers, you could use an array. You use the push function to add to an array.

```js
var guessedNumbers = [];
guessedNumbers.push(24);
guessedNumbers.push(36);

for (i = 0; i < guessedNumbers.length; i++) {
  document.write(guessedNumbers[i] + "<br />");
}
```

Comment: So since the array will be loaded with whatever numbers the user enters into the textbox, would I just replace guessedNumbers.push(24); with guessedNumbers.push(guess); ? Also, since the array will be growing with each guess entered, where would I need to put this for loop?

Comment: Yes, if you want to push their guess instead of a literal number, you would use `guessedNumbers.push(guess);`. The for loop was just a demonstration of how to loop through the array. Inside the for loop, you could check if any of the `guessedNumbers` elements matched the `guess`, and let the user know they already guessed that number.